# Conditional probability for a random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If I had a random variable, $X$, such that $P(X≥3) = m$ and $P(X\geq9) = n$ and wanted to show that $P(X<3 | X<9) = \frac{m-1}{n-1}$

I let $P(X<3) = 1 - P(X≥3) = 1 - m$

Then:

$P(X<3 | X<9) = \frac{P(X<3 \cap X<9)}{P(X<9)}$

$P(X<3 | X<9) = \frac{P(X<3) * P(X<9)}{P(X<9)}$

I'm left with the following:

$P(X<3 | X<9) = P(X<3)$

...which does not give me the proof required.

Does anyone know how I can prove the above statement?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139138/discussion-on-question-by-george-orwell-conditional-probability-for-a-random-var).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that $(X<3)$ and $(X<9)$ are independent. But this is almost never the case. Indeed if you know that $X<3$ then necessarily $X<9$, right? This is the opposite of independence, one event making the other automatically true.

Because of that, the event $(X<3$ and $X<9)$ is defined redundantly, and simplifies to just $(X<3)$. This is what your teacher used.

Comment: In that case, it just simplifies down to (1 - m) rather than (m - 1) / (n - 1)?

Comment: No, you have $\dfrac {P((X<3) \cap (X<9)}{P(X<9)} = \dfrac {P(X<3)}{P(X<9)} = \dfrac {m-1}{n-1}$.

Comment: But, i thought it simplified down to P (X < 3), which is (m - 1)?

Comment: Your simplification to $P(X<3)$ is wrong because you use $P(X<3 \cap X<9) = P(X<3) P(X<9)$ which holds **only if the two events are independent** which is not the case here.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be independent? And what would be the formula used for a dependent event in order to calculate this?

Comment: There is no formula for dependent events. $P(A\cap B)$ can then be anything from $0$ to $P(A)$ or $P(B)$ depending on how dependent the two events are. So you have to look at the specific situation. Here we use the fact that $(X<3) \cap (X<9)$ just means $(X<3)$. Indeed saying that something is smaller than 9 **and** smaller than 3 just means it's smaller than 3.